# Displaying posts details using Json returns undefine in vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

After successfully fetching posts using JSON, I also want to display the details of the post on the post details.vue page but I get an undefined error.
I am sure there is something I am not doing right but I can't figure it out as well. Please someone help me with an idea on how to figure it out. Thanks.

**Here is the code to fetch the posts from JSON**

```
<div class="w-full lg:w-3/4 mb-7 p-1">

          <div class="max-w-md bg-white rounded-xl shadow-md overflow-hidden md:max-w-2xl mb-6" v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
           <div class="flex">
             <div class="shrink-0">
                <img class="h-28 w-full object-cover md:h-full md:w-28" src="../assets/img.png" alt="Man looking at item at a store">
             </div>
             <div class="pl-4 pt-2">
                <div class="uppercase tracking-wide text-sm text-indigo-500 font-semibold">{{post.cat}}</div>
                <router-link :to="{name: 'PostDetails', params:{id: post.id} }">
                <h1 class="block mt-1 text-lg leading-tight font-medium text-black hover:underline font-bold">{{post.title}}</h1>
                </router-link>
                <!-- <p class="mt-2 text-slate-500">Getting a new business off the ground is a lot of hard work.</p> -->
             </div>
           </div>
          </div>

        </div>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
export defualt {
data(){
   return{
   posts:[]
 }
},
mounted(){
fetch('http://localhost:3000/posts')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => this.posts = data)
.catch(err => console.log(error.message))
 }
}
</script>
```

**Code to display posts details**

```
<template>
<h1>Current Post You Are reading</h1>
<div v-if="post">
    <p>The Post Id is {{id}}</p>
    <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
</div>
```

**Js**

```
<script>
```

export default {

```
props:['id'],

data(){

    return{
        post: null
    }
},

mounted(){
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/posts/' + this.id)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => this.post = data)
    .catch(err => console.log(error.message))
}
```

}

**The Outcome**

[image]

Comment: It looks like you're trying to render `<PostDetails />` without passing it the id (e.g: `<PostDetails :id="post.id" />`). And you're not showing us the `<template>` of `Posts.vue`, which could tells us more about why you're seeing this error. If you are passing the `:id` as prop to the details, it means that at least one of your `posts` has an `id` value of `undefined`. The simplest way to filter it out would be `<PostDetails :id="post.id" v-if="post.id" />`.

Comment: Also note your question is currently *off-topic* by [SO] standards. Please read [ask]. Namely, you're posting pictures of code instead of code. If anyone wants to help you and test out your code, they would have to type in the code from the picture to test it. This shows zero respect for that person's time and effort. If someone else asked you to type in a bunch of code code from a picture just to help them figure out what's wrong with it, would you do it, knowing they could have simply copy/pasted it as text?

Answer (score 0):

I think my sample will help you,

#### PostList.vue

```js
<template>
      <div>
        <div v-for="item in posts" :key="item.id">
          <router-link :to="'/postdetails/'+item.id">{{item.first_name}}</router-link>
          <h1>{{item.first_name}}</h1>
          <h2>{{item.last_name}}</h2>
          <div>{{item.email}}</div>
          <div>
            <img v-bind:src="item.avatar" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'PostList',
    data() {
      return {
        posts: []
      }
    },
    created() {
      fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
          this.posts = data.data
          console.log("this.posts", this.posts)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
  }
</script>
```

#### PostDetails.vue

```js
<template>
      <div>
        <div v-for="item in posts" :key="item.id">
          <h1>{{ item.first_name }}</h1>
          <h2>{{ item.last_name }}</h2>
          <div>{{ item.email }}</div>
          <div>
            <img v-bind:src="item.avatar" alt="" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
<script>
  export default {
    name: "PostDetails",
    data() {
      return {
        msg: "welcome to PostList page",
        posts: [],
        id: this.$route.params && this.$route.params.id,
      };
    },
    created() {
      fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users/" + this.id)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          this.posts = data;
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    },
  };
</script>
```

And in router index.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue' 
import Router from 'vue-router' 
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld' 
import PostList from '@/components/PostList' 
import PostDetails from '@/components/PostDetails' 
Vue.use(Router) 
export default new Router(
      { routes: [ 
         { path: '/', redirect: { name:'PostList' }},
         { path: '/postlist', name: 'PostList', component: PostList },
      { path: '/postdetails/:id', name: 'PostDetails', component: PostDetails }
    ]}
)
```